# При скачивании файла с сервера файл сначала кешируется, а потом дает пользователю выбрать место загрузки. Пользователь не видит прогресс загрузки

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url, axios

Следующий код предназначен для скачивания видеофайла с сервера.
Однако после отправления запроса файл сначала кешируется, не оповещая об этом никого, а после этого потом предлагает выбрать место на компьютере, куда необходимо поместить файл, и сразу падает скачанный в загрузки браузера. Из-за этого пользователь не видит, скачивается ли файл вообще или просто ничего не происходит, если файл большой. Как сделать так, чтобы сразу после клика на кнопку, пользователю сначала дали выбрать место, куда нужно загрузить файл, а затем закачка файла началась, а прогресс закачки был виден в загрузках браузера

```
downloadFile(timestamp, camid, t) {
 downloading.value = true;
 t == true ? type.value = 'motion' : type.value = 'archive';
 downloading.value = false
 axios
  .get(`/api/v1/archive/${camid}/record/${timestamp}?record_type=${type.value}`, {
   responseType: 'blob',
   .then(function(response){
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
    link.download = `rec=${camid}-${timestamp}.ts`;
    link.click();
   })
   .then(() => downloading.value = false)
   .catch((e) => error.value = e);
  },
```